# How to display whole table in the output in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

After running my code in Jupyter Notebook to output a table which is really big, the middle part of the table was not displayed, it's showing as dots inbetween rows no. 4 and 79 (see attachment below). How do I get Jupyter Notebook to display the whole table? I am using Anaconda. Many thanks.

[image: jupyter tables]

Comment: If you have to show specific columns, then you should select those

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add below two lines to see all the rows /columns

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', n) #replace n with the number of columns you want to see completely
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', n) #replace n with the number of rows you want to see completely
```

Comment: For the whole table, without specifying the precise number, this worked for me:
`pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)`
`pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)`